# passport - Filling correctly Place of birth in eTA request

Tags: canada, eta

I'm filling an eTA request for Canada. There is a question about

> City/town of birth (required)

In my passport my place of birth is not written entirely (i.e., last digit is missing) since it is quite long (4 words with a total of 24 characters).

When answering to this question should I put what it is written in the passport or the full place of birth?

**update**

Maybe it is worth to mention that it's a [Biometric passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometric_passport) so the chip contains my information. The place of birth information contained is the right one (i.e. full birth place name).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what town is this? Also, I would put down the full place of birth. You were born in town XYZ not Town XY.

Comment: its a small town, so I would prefer not to write entirely. With x's it's the following "xxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxY (ZZ)"  and the Y is missing on the passport for space problem. ZZ is the province.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've called the Passport Agency who released my passport. My birth place is cut automatically by the printer but in the chip there is my full birth place, so in the case they see a mismatch they can check.

Therefore, they told me to put my full birth place, even if it does not match what it is written on my passport.